# Kivy Code to display ListView crashes

Tags: python, listview, crash, window, kivy

I am very new to Kivy.Basically I am trying to display a list when a button (Main button) is clicked. I used the coding style given in the kivy documentation.
But when I run the python file (by Sendto kivy in windows) the command line appears for few seconds and then closes, no errors displayed.

Where am I going wrong ? Is it possible to prevent the console from closing when compilation is not successful, so that I can view the log messages ?

Here is the main.py and baseclass.kv code:

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):    
    pass

class BaseClass(App):
    def list_button(self):
        dropdown = CustomDropDown()
        dropdown.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(dropdown, 'text', x))
        self.root.add_widget(dropdown)

    def build(self):                     
        return CustomDropDown()   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BaseClass().run()
```

And here is the kv file:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#:kivy 1.0
#:import kivy kivy

<CustomDropDown>:   
        Button:
            text: 'My first Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 44
            on_release: root.select('item1')
        Label:
            text: 'Unselectable item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 44
        Button:
            text: 'My second Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 44

<BaseClass>:
        Button:
            text: 'Main'
            width: '200dp'
            height:'200dp'
            id: main_but
            on_release: app.list_button()
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me once I fixed the indentation of your kv - use 4 spaces per indentation level.

You would see this as the error traceback in the console if you run the code in a way that doesn't close it immediately. I'm sure this is possible, and you should find out how, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: I tried fixing the kv to 4 spaces per indentation level, but the program still closes abruptly.
 Yes, it would be nice to know to do the error traceback thing. I tried googling it, but nothing worked there too.